# ProgressBar not displaying - await

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am having trouble getting my progress spinner displaying as I am loading in data from my database.

This is the progress bar on axml page:

```
<ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/HomeProgressBar"
      android:visibility="invisible"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:theme="@style/CircularProgress"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"/>
```

Creating the progress bar object on activity page:

```
public class HomeActivity : Activity
    {
      private ProgressBar progressBar;
```

Method that uses the progress bar:

```
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task LoadPostData()
    {
        mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstHomeItems);
        mItems = new List<Post>();

        progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        mListView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

        var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseURL);
        var posts = await firebase.Child("posts").OnceAsync<Post>();

        mItems.Clear();
        adapter = null;
        foreach (var item in posts)
        {
            Post post = new Post();
            post.ActivityID = item.Key;
            post.OwnerID = item.Object.OwnerID;
            post.ActivityTitle = item.Object.ActivityTitle;
            post.ActivityDetails = item.Object.ActivityDetails;
            post.ActivityDate = item.Object.ActivityDate;
            post.ActivityTime = item.Object.ActivityTime;
            post.ActivityAddress = item.Object.ActivityAddress;
            post.ActivityTown = item.Object.ActivityTown;
            post.ActivitySport = item.Object.ActivitySport;
            post.ActivityEmail = item.Object.ActivityEmail;
            post.ActivityPhone = item.Object.ActivityPhone;

            // Remove Old events
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - post.ActivityDate;

            // Remove event if it is old
            if (ts.TotalDays > 1)
            {
                // Remove old posts from the database
                await firebase.Child("posts").Child(item.Key).DeleteAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                mItems.Add(post);
            }
        }

        adapter = new HomeListViewAdapter(this, mItems);
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        mListView.Adapter = adapter;

        // Hide ProgressBar when data is loaded
        progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        mListView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }
```

This is how I call the LoadPostData method and populate the progress bar from the OnCreate:

```
// Spinning Progress Bar
            progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.HomeProgressBar);

await LoadPostData();
```

Comment: Do you `await` inside the LoadPostData for the database data retrieval? Unless you add the full code we can only guess.

Comment: I added all the code now Gusman

Comment: For what I see everything seems to be ok, the only doubt I have is where you retrieve the ProgressBar. Assuming you retrieve it anywhere else and it's correct, try to add a button which only hides the list and shows the progressbar, if the progressbar does not show you have some error on your layout, else remove pieces of the current function until the bar is shown.

Answer (score 0):

All the User Interface management must be done in the main thread. You should make the ProgressBar appear in the main thread and then create the task that loads the data.

Or use an AsyncTask and show the ProgressBar in preExecute and hide it in postExecute, both methods will be called on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can only update your UI in your mainthread. Otherwise it would not work. Try on run main thread:

```
YourActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()      
        {      
            public void run()      
            {      
                yourProgressBar.show();   
            }      

        });
```

This is not recommended. The better way is use a asyncTask and put your UI updates in onPostExecute();  .